# How to know when updates to the Google AppEngine HRD datastore are complete?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a long running job that updates 1000's of entity groups. I want to kick off a 2nd job afterwards that will have to assume all of those items have been updated. Since there are so many entity groups, I can't do it in a transaction, so i've just scheduled the 2nd job to run 15 minutes after the 1st completes using task queues.

Is there a better way?

Is it even safe to assume that 15 minutes gives a promise that the datastore is in sync with my previous calls?

I am using high replication.

In the google IO videos about HRD, they give a list of ways to deal with eventual consistency.  One of them was to "accept it".  Some updates (like twitter posts) don't need to be consistent with the next read.  But they also said something like "hey, we're only talking miliseconds to a couple of seconds before they are consistent". Is that time frame documented anywhere else?  Is it safe assuming that waiting 1 minute after a write before reading again will mean all my preivous writes are there in the read?

The mention of that is at the 39:30 mark in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=xO015C3R6dw

Comment: I've given a partial answer below, but can you give any more information on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically I'm inserting or updating 1000's of entities.  When that job is complete, I need to apply a rank to the items. So I run a query that selects all of the records and orders them by the field I'm concerned about ranking. Then I update the ranks in another entity type.  That rank will obviously be off if entities are missing from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find this statement:

> With eventual consistency, more than 99.9% of your writes are available for queries within a few seconds.

at the bottom of this page:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/hr/overview.html

So, for my application, a 0.1% chance of it not being there on the next read is probably OK.  However, I do plan to redesign my schema to make use of ancestor queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any built in way to determine if the updates are done. I would recommend adding a lastUpdated field to your entities and updating it with your first job, then check for the timestamp on the entity you're updating with the 2nd before running... kind of a hack but it should work.

Interested to see if anybody has a better solution. Kinda hope they do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is automatic as long as you are getting entities without changing the consistency to Eventual. The HRD puts data to a majority of relevant datastore servers before returning. If you are calling the asynchronous version of put, you'll need to call get on all the Future objects before you can be sure it's completed.

If however you are querying for the items in the first job, there's no way to be sure that the index has been updated.

So for example...

If you are updating a property on every entity (but not creating any entities), then retrieving all entities of that kind. You can do a keys-only query followed by a batch get (which is approximately as fast/cheap as doing a normal query) and be sure that you have all updates applied.

On the other hand, if you're adding new entities or updating a property in the first process that the second process queries, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: My 1st process both updates and creates new entities.So there is no way to be sure the entities will be present in an immediate call to read those same items from the datastore no matter how long I wait to execute the 2nd process (15 minutes or 15 days)?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "read" - if you mean "get" then yes, they will always be there. However if you mean "query" or "find" then no. You could however do a keys-only query for each entity that you've added - only allowing the second process to execute once every added entity is present in a query result.

Comment: You mean persist or update 1000's of items and keep their keys in memory.  Then, when I read them back via a query, make sure all of the keys are present in the results?  If they are present, is the data guaranteed to be in sync with the updates that ran seconds before?

Even if that is a valid approach, at some point my 1,000's will become 1,000,000's and I would like to stay away from keeping that much data in memory.  Right now I'm avoiding that by using cursors and only operating on a few 100 items at once.

Comment: I mean keep the list of items that you've added. If that's likely to be 1,000,000's then fair enough, but I assumed that although you might be updating a huge dataset, the number of NEW items would be large at most.